# i take a string from arraylist and have trouble with lucene tokenize

Tags: java, lucene

I have an ArrayList with some strings, and, for every string, I remove the stopwords and add it to a new ArrayList.

But, Netbeans returns an error:

```
"AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LUCENE_47
```

...

```
at
org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardTokenizer.init(StandardTokenizer.java:144)
at
org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardTokenizer.<init>(StandardTokenizer.java:132)
```

The code to send the string is:

```
for(i=0;i<listR.size();i++){
    str=listR.get(i);
    try {
        str=st.StopWordString(str);
        listSt.add(str);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(PanelAuto.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

And the method I use to remove the stopwords is:

```
public String StopWordString(String incoming) throws IOException{

    Tokenizer tokenizer = new StandardTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_44,new StringReader(incoming));

    final StandardFilter standardFilter = new StandardFilter(Version.LUCENE_44, tokenizer);
    final StopFilter stopFilter = new StopFilter(Version.LUCENE_44, standardFilter, StopAnalyzer.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS_SET);

    final CharTermAttribute charTermAttribute = tokenizer.addAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);

    stopFilter.reset();
    while(stopFilter.incrementToken()) {
        final String token = charTermAttribute.toString().toString();
        list.add(token);
    }

    for(i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
     str += list.get(i)+" ";
    } 

    return str;
}
```

The error is thrown on this line:

```
Tokenizer tokenizer = new StandardTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_44,new StringReader(incoming));
```

Comment: And, what is this error?  `ClassDefNotFound`?  `NullPointer`?  `IllegalAccess`?

Comment: Sorry i forget to write the error , is 
"AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: LUCENE_47

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have mismatched versions of the Lucene jars in your classpath.  Particularly, it appears you have `lucene-analyzers.common-4.7.X.jar`, but an earlier version of lucene core (perhaps `lucene-core-4.4.X.jar`?).  You have set the tokenizer to use an earlier algorithm, but you still need to use jars from the same version of Lucene.  I believe this is the particular line which directly causes the issue, which gives an example of why that is:

```
if (matchVersion.onOrAfter(Version.LUCENE_47))
```

(The `Version` class lives in lucene-core)

If you've upgraded lucene-core to version 4.7 already, you may have an old jar in your classpath that you need to remove.

Comment: Thi is the error i have 4.4 and now with new version core jar everything is work perfect